# wp7 insert XAML inside other XAML?

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

How can i insert XMAL inside other XMAL?

is this possible in wp7?

If anyone know concept help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of like reusable components? A'la iframes in `HTML`? You might be interested in `UserControls`. [Here's](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-6-using-user-controls-to-implement-master-detail-scenarios.aspx) an excellent tutorial about.

So first you create a new usercontrol eg. `"MyUserControl.xaml"` (File -> New item -> User Control) and add some components to it. Later on you can add a reference to it in another XAML file and use it simply: `<MyProject:MyUserControl x:Name="something" />`

It's all explained in the tutorial I linked :).